# I can't use salt-api

Tags: curl, salt-stack

I'm trying to use salt-api but I can't connect to it. First, I installed salt-api in the master, then I added the following configuration to the master file:

```
external_auth:
  pam:
    david:
      - .*

rest_cherrypy:
  port: 8080
  debug: True
```

But when I tried to connect via curl, it didn't work:

```
curl -si localhost:8080/login -H "Accept: application/json" -d username='david' -d password='password' -d eauth='pam' > /tmp/cookies.txt
```

I got the following error message:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 3):

First you need to make sure `salt-api` service is running.

You can do by running it in the foreground for testing/debug like:

```
salt-api -l debug
```

Try this and update your question if still have issues